# How to create multiple executables using makefile from a single target

Tags: build, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to build excutables for multiple files which are built in the same way. When i run make all the excutables should be generated. I am getting error at prerequisites part of the macro.

```
CXX       = g++
CXX_FLAGS = -g -Wall
LD_FLAGS  =

INC_DIR  = -I/my/path/include
SRC_DIR  = .
LIB_DIR  = -L$/my/path/lib
OBJ_DIR  = obj
EXE_DIR  = exe

SRCS := $(foreach s_dir, $(SRC_DIR), $(wildcard $(s_dir)/*.cpp))
OBJS := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(SRCS))
EXES := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp, $(EXE_DIR)/%.out, $(SRCS))


all:  create_directories create_objects create_exes

create_directories:
    @echo "Creating $(OBJ_DIR) and $(EXE_DIR)..."
    @mkdir -p obj
    @mkdir -p exe

create_objects:
  $(foreach b_dir, $(OBJ_DIR), $(eval $(call build-objects, $(b_dir))))

create_exes:
  $(foreach ot, $(EXE_DIR), $(eval $(call build-exes, $(ot))))

define build-objects
$1/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) $(INC_DIR) -MMD -MP -c $$< -o $$@
endef


define build-exes
$1/%.out:obj/%.o 
    $(CXX) $(LD_FLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIB_DIR) -lmylib
endef
```

Is this a right way to do generate multiple exes or any other simple way?

Comment: Each source file corresponds to one and only one executable, is that right?

Comment: The `create_objects` and `create_exes` targets have no recipes here (`eval` returns nothing). You are evaluating the pattern rules that can build things in their recipe location. That's an odd thing to be doing. Are you trying to have those be available to make during the primary execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading this makefile right, then it's much too complicated.

First let's have a rule to build object files:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) $(INC_DIR) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@
```

Now if we're not sure about the existence of `obj/`, we could add a rule to create it, but for the moment let's just put in a failsafe (we'll come back to this later):

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) $(INC_DIR) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@
```

And a similar rule to build the executables:

```
$(EXE_DIR)/%.out: $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o
    @mkdir -p $(EXE_DIR)
    $(CXX) $(LD_FLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIB_DIR) -lmylib
```

And finally (at the top) some variables, the lists of files, and the `all` rule:

```
CXX       = g++
CXX_FLAGS = -g -Wall
LD_FLAGS  = 
INC_DIR   = -I/my/path/include

SRC_DIR  = .
LIB_DIR  = -L$/my/path/lib
OBJ_DIR  = obj
EXE_DIR  = exe

SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
EXES := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp, $(EXE_DIR)/%.out, $(SRCS))
# Let the object files take care of themselves

all: $(EXES)
```

That's all you need. Once this is working perfectly, we can discuss refinements like rules for building directories.